# how to install and test a form using selenium

Tags: php, selenium

[image]im trying to learn about testing. Actually im a developr, i want to install selenium. initially i installed selenium IDE and corresponding ADD ONs for firefox.  Is that enough for testing a webpage in php?
after referring some tutorials,i heard about selenium RC. Already started the installing of RC through cmd, fact is that i don't know whether it is installed or not.
And pls tell me about selenium tool and how to test a page other than login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture mouse clicks and other events using the Selenium IDE and record those captures into test cases. The Selenium IDE recorder will keep track of whatever page you navigate to so you can test more than your login page.

You can also use the Selenium WebDriver and write your tests in languages such as Java, C#, Ruby, Python, and Node.

There are a number of tutorials out there to help you with this. Good luck.

http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.jsp
https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/GettingStarted